# How to create a image and content slider in Flex?

Tags: image, apache-flex, slideshow

I would like to create a image and content slider in Flex. There are many jquery plugings available 
(cfr. Flexslider http://flex.madebymufffin.com/) but i can't find an alternative for Flex.

Can anyone explain me how i can implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ah it just so happens I already made this... a long time ago so it's Flex 3 but I believe it works as is in Flex 4, I've integrated this with other Flex 4 projects and have since made some performance improvements (mainly opting for Group over Canvas and did some deferred instantation since we decided to use it as the backbone for a pretty complex site).

http://www.shaunhusain.com/ImageSlider/

http://www.shaunhusain.com/ImageSlider/srcview/index.html

Should allow you to drag and snaps to the tile with it's top left corner nearest the top left of the container itself, also can use keyboard navigation left right up down so long as it has focus, and I made those buttons on top that can be used to trigger the movements.  Basically I tried to overload that example with all possible options so I can just copy it and strip off what I don't want.  It also turns out this translates pretty well to touch screens even though I didn't own one when I wrote it, the snap to nearest thing works alright on an android (even with that version which is totally not optimized for mobile).  Oh yeah and you can use - and + on the keyboard or the scroll wheel to zoom, doubt if that's really ever necessary but it seemed like a cool idea at the time.

Comment: It's definitely very cool! Thank you! I'll certainly can use this! Grtz

Comment: Hi Shaun, I found your image slider to be great but i am having a small issue changing the heights of the left and right nav buttons. I was wondering if you could think of any reason for this.  Thanks Anto

Comment: @Anto ah well haven't looked at this code in a long time but in looking it over again it appears I was using the top, bottom, left, right constraints for sizing the buttons and the width or the height just to give them some "thickness" so to speak.  If you'd like to pastebin your modification of the code I might be able to point out the issue.

Comment: @shaunhusain That was it, I didn't think that the top and bottom constraints would stop the height from working so with a bit of adjustment it is working grand now. Thanks Shaun!